# How can I insert a column that concatenates 2 other columns' data together in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use pandas to populate a column by concatenating 2 other columns in the dataframe.

Input Table

```
City    State
Boston  MA
Austin  TX
```

I want to add a 'Location' column.
Input Table

```
City    State    Location
Boston  MA       Boston, MA
Austin  TX       Austin, TX
```

Currently, this is the code I'm using:

```
df['Location'] = None
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.Location[i] = str(df.loc[i, 'City']) + ", " + str(df.loc[i, 'State'])
```

I've tried using these 2 methods:

```
df['Location'] = '{}, {}'.format(str(df['City']), str(df['State']))
df['Location'] = str(df['City']) + ', ' + str(df['State'])
```

But only get this output:

```
City    State    Location
Boston  MA       Boston
Austin  TX       Austin
```

If you could also explain why I'm getting these results, that would be helpful in my future understanding of pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy with vectorised string concatenation.

```
df['Location'] = df.City + ', ' + df.State

     City State    Location
0  Boston    MA  Boston, MA
1  Austin    TX  Austin, TX
```

Comment: Do you know why this doesn't work?

    `df['Location'] = '{}-{}'.format(str(df.City), str(df.State))`